# 'ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: webpack, ethereum, solidity, truffle

So, I have been following tutorials of Eat The Blocks on ToDo List Ethereum DApp. Done till step 6, but while running the command `npm run dev-front` I am getting this error.

```
> Project@1.0.0 dev-front L:\Project
> ENV=development node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch

'ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Project@1.0.0 dev-front: `ENV=development node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Project@1.0.0 dev-front script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is the link to the tutorial https://eattheblocks.com/todo-list-ethereum-dapp-step6/
I am developing on Windows 10.

So I looked in some of the forums, it said to set environment variable path is different in Windows 10.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev-front": "ENV=development node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch",
    "dev-back": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

This is the code. How do we set the environment path?
It would be nice if anyone helps me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think on Windows you want `set ENV=development & node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch`. (`set` and `&`)

Answer (score 6):

**set** ENVFILE **&** npm run android...will work in windows. In MAC it is not needed.

"set" and "&" is imp.

Answer (score 0):

check the answer in this post. you may have to install dotenv as mentioned in the answer in the below post.

[error 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254781/error-env-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)