# Error in rule configure_veins_vlc, configure_veins, protobuf

Tags: python, omnet++, veins, sumo, protoc

My question is regarding [veins-gym](https://github.com/tkn-tub/serpentine-env/blob/master/examples/Tutorial_Using_the_Serpentine_Scenario.ipynb). The dependencies highlighted at the beginning of that file work well. However, I receive an error when running `snakemake -jall`. Here is a log file

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Provided cores: 8
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job                    count    min threads    max threads
-------------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                        1              1              1
build                      2              8              8
build_veins                2              8              8
build_veins_vlc            2              8              8
configure                  1              1              1
configure_veins            1              1              1
configure_veins_vlc        1              1              1
protobuf                   1              1              1
total                     11              1              8

Select jobs to execute...

[Sat Dec 18 23:08:10 2021]
rule configure_veins:
    input: lib/veins/src/veins/base/messages/AirFrame.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/base/messages/BorderMsg.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/base/messages/MacPkt.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11pMessage.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/AckTimeOutMessage.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/AirFrame11p.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/BaseFrame1609_4.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/DemoSafetyMessage.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/DemoServiceAdvertisement.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/Mac80211Ack.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/Mac80211Pkt.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/PhyControlMessage.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/messages/TraCITrafficLightMessage.msg, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/BaseConnectionManager.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/ChannelAccess.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/ConnectionManager.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDebug.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDirect.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseApplLayer.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseBattery.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseLayer.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseMacLayer.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseMobility.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseModule.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseWorldUtility.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BatteryAccess.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/Antenna.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/BaseDecider.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/BasePhyLayer.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/ChannelInfo.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/Decider.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/PhyUtils.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/toolbox/Signal.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/toolbox/SignalUtils.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/toolbox/Spectrum.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/Coord.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/Heading.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/NetwToMacControlInfo.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/SimpleAddress.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/winsupport.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/BreakpointPathlossModel.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/NakagamiFading.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/PERModel.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/SimpleObstacleShadowing.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/SimplePathlossModel.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/TwoRayInterferenceModel.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/VehicleObstacleShadowing.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci/MyVeinsApp.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemoRSU11p.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/LinearMobility.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIColor.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICoordinateTransformation.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCILauncher.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIRegionOfInterest.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScreenRecorder.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIVehicleInserter.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/MobileHostObstacle.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/Obstacle.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/ObstacleControl.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/VehicleObstacleControl.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/NistErrorRate.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/PhyLayer80211p.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/SampledAntenna1D.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/BBoxLookup.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/HasLogProxy.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/annotations/AnnotationDummy.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/annotations/AnnotationManager.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/TraCITrafficLightInterface.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/TraCITrafficLightProgram.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/logics/TraCITrafficLightAbstractLogic.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/logics/TraCITrafficLightSimpleLogic.cc, lib/veins/src/veins/veins.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/BaseConnectionManager.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/ChannelAccess.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/ConnectionManager.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntry.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDebug.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/connectionManager/NicEntryDirect.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/AddressingInterface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseApplLayer.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseBattery.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseLayer.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseMacLayer.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseMobility.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseModule.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BaseWorldUtility.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/modules/BatteryAccess.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/AnalogueModel.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/Antenna.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/BaseDecider.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/BasePhyLayer.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/ChannelInfo.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/Decider.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/DeciderToPhyInterface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/MacToPhyInterface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/PhyToMacControlInfo.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/phyLayer/PhyUtils.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/toolbox/Signal.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/toolbox/SignalUtils.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/toolbox/Spectrum.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/AntennaPosition.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/Coord.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/EnumBitset.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/FindModule.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/FWMath.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/Heading.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/HostState.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/MacToNetwControlInfo.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/Move.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/NetwToMacControlInfo.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/PassedMessage.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/POA.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/SimpleAddress.h, lib/veins/src/veins/base/utils/winsupport.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/BreakpointPathlossModel.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/NakagamiFading.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/PERModel.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/SimpleObstacleShadowing.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/SimplePathlossModel.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/TwoRayInterferenceModel.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/analogueModel/VehicleObstacleShadowing.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci/MyVeinsApp.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemoRSU11p.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayerToMac1609_4Interface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac80211pToPhy11pInterface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/LinearMobility.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/ParBuffer.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIColor.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConnection.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIConstants.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICoord.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICoordinateTransformation.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCILauncher.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIRegionOfInterest.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerForker.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScreenRecorder.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIVehicleInserter.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/VehicleSignal.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/MobileHostObstacle.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/Obstacle.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/ObstacleControl.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/obstacle/VehicleObstacleControl.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211pToPhy80211pInterface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/DeciderResult80211.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/NistErrorRate.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/PhyLayer80211p.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/phy/SampledAntenna1D.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/BBoxLookup.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/Consts80211p.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/ConstsPhy.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/HasLogProxy.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/MacToPhyControlInfo11p.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/SignalManager.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/annotations/AnnotationDummy.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/annotations/AnnotationManager.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/TraCITrafficLightInterface.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/TraCITrafficLightProgram.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/logics/TraCITrafficLightAbstractLogic.h, lib/veins/src/veins/modules/world/traci/trafficLight/logics/TraCITrafficLightSimpleLogic.h
    output: lib/veins/src/Makefile
    jobid: 3
    resources: tmpdir=C:\Users\ROSTYS~1\AppData\Local\Temp


[Sat Dec 18 23:08:10 2021]
rule configure_veins_vlc:
    input: lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/messages/AirFrameVlc.msg, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/messages/VlcMessage.msg, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/AntennaHeadlight.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/AntennaTaillight.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/AntennaVlc.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/DeciderVlc.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/Photodiode.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/PhyLayerVlc.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/RadiationPattern.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/Splitter.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/VlcConnectionManager.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/EmpiricalLightModel.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/FittedEmpiricalLightModel.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/LsvLightModel.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/VehicleObstacleShadowingForVlc.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/application/simpleVlcApp/SimpleVlcApp.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/mac/MacLayerVlc.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/utility/Utils.cc, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/AntennaHeadlight.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/AntennaTaillight.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/AntennaVlc.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/DeciderVlc.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/Photodiode.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/PhyLayerVlc.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/RadiationPattern.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/Splitter.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/veins-vlc.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/VlcConnectionManager.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/EmpiricalLightModel.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/FittedEmpiricalLightModel.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/LsvLightModel.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/analogueModel/VehicleObstacleShadowingForVlc.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/application/simpleVlcApp/SimpleVlcApp.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/mac/MacLayerVlc.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/utility/ConstsVlc.h, lib/veins-vlc/src/veins-vlc/utility/Utils.h
    output: lib/veins-vlc/src/Makefile
    jobid: 5
    resources: tmpdir=C:\Users\ROSTYS~1\AppData\Local\Temp

[Sat Dec 18 23:08:10 2021]
rule protobuf:
    input: src/protobuf/veinsgym.proto
    output: src/protobuf/veinsgym.pb.cc, src/protobuf/veinsgym.pb.h
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: file=veinsgym
    resources: tmpdir=C:\Users\ROSTYS~1\AppData\Local\Temp

[Sat Dec 18 23:08:10 2021]
[Sat Dec 18 23:08:10 2021]
Error in rule configure_veins_vlc:
Error in rule configure_veins:
    jobid: 5
    jobid: 3
    output: lib/veins-vlc/src/Makefile
    output: lib/veins/src/Makefile
    shell:
        env -C lib/veins-vlc ./configure --with-veins=../veins
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
    shell:
        env -C lib/veins ./configure
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

[Sat Dec 18 23:08:10 2021]

Error in rule protobuf:
    jobid: 7
    output: src/protobuf/veinsgym.pb.cc, src/protobuf/veinsgym.pb.h
    shell:
        env protoc --proto_path src/protobuf --cpp_out src/protobuf src/protobuf/veinsgym.proto
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: C:\Users\User\git\serpentine-env\.snakemake\log\2021-12-18T230810.057922.snakemake.log
```

I believe that the error is in the command `env`, becasue in the command prompt I also get

`'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I could probably change it to the command mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63456002/15452880), however I cannot find the source file, where this command is called.

I use windows 10, 64 bit
Python 3.8
veins-gym 0.3.0
gym 0.21.0
omnetpp 5.6.2
sumo-1.8.0
veins 5.2
protoc-3.19.1

Any advice on how to tackle this problem is very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Veins-Gym is not supported on MinGW for Windows. Even if you managed to make this work, you seem to be compiling an OMNeT++ simulation consisting of multiple shared libraries on MinGW for Windows. You will likely get much better results doing this on Instant Veins or a similar Linux/Unix system or on the Windows Subsystem for Linux.